# Adding a column to multiple files (900+) using #SBATCH

Tags: awk, sed, terminal, sbatch

I am trying to add a column to a file:

```
1       12098   12258   0.00
1       12553   12721   1.37
1       13331   13701   34.69
1       30334   30503   0.00
1       35045   35544   0.00
1       35618   35778   0.00
1       69077   70017   0.24
1       324294  324394  0.68
1       324427  325605  3.18
```

so it looks like this:

```
1       12098   12258   unknown   0.00
1       12553   12721   unknown   1.37
1       13331   13701   unknown   34.69
1       30334   30503   unknown   0.00
1       35045   35544   unknown   0.00
1       35618   35778   unknown   0.00
1       69077   70017   unknown   0.24
1       324294  324394  unknown   0.68
1       324427  325605  unknown   3.18
```

I have managed to do it using this command:

```
awk '$3 = $3 FS "unknown"' <file> > <new_file>
```

However I have over 900 files that I need to do this too and output to a new file on each occasion. I find awk complicated to understand and was wondering whether there is a way to do this using #SBATCH scripts or any other method for multiple files at a time?

I am pretty new to stack overflow, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Does retaining the spacing between columns matter to you? If so is that tabs or blanks or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a an *alternative* `sed` solution to make this change and save changes inline:

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/[^[:blank:]]+$/unknown &/' *.txt
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava thanks for this! It worked well. I was wondering whether it is possible to perform this command only on file names that are listed in a separate file? Thanks again

Comment: Let's say that filenames are stored in a file called `files.txt` then you can use: `sed -E -i.bak 's/[^[:blank:]]+$/unknown &/' $(<files.txt)`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @anubhava worked well! One final question, can you get sed to work in the background?

Comment: Yes just place `&`  at the end of command like: `sed -E -i.bak 's/[^[:blank:]]+$/unknown &/' $(<files.txt) &`

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution as per OP's comments to save output into outputfiles try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  close(out_file)
  sub(/\./,"_new&",FILENAME)
  out_file=FILENAME
}
{
  $NF="unknown" OFS $NF
  print > (out_file)
}'  *.bed
```

---

---

In case you are not worried about the spaces in between lines then you could try following.

```
awk '{$NF="unknown" OFS $NF} 1'  Input_file
```

OR with GNU `awk` latest versions try:

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '{$NF="unknown" OFS $NF} 1'  Input_file(s)
```

---

---

To make spaces look good you could add `column` to above command too:

```
awk '{$NF="unknown" OFS $NF} 1'  Input_file | column -t
```

OR with GNU `awk` latest versions try:

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '{$NF="unknown" OFS $NF} 1'  Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am wanting to do this simultaneously for multiple files is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: @hdjc90, if you have latest version of GNU awk it has inplace save along with backup of files too, remove backup files option `-v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak` in case you don't want backup of files, lemme know?

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 thanks for your help. To clarify, I would like to enter a command to do all my files (e.g. *.bed) and output them all (e.g. *_new.bed)?

Comment: @hdjc90, Could you please check my EDIT solution and lemme know if that helps you?